How to connect inherited submodule with inherited compound module
I need to modify some functions of Gptp module in TsnSwitch.
For this in NED file I added submodule which extends Gptp
simple ExtendedGptp extends Gptp
{
  
}


Then I added compound module, inherited from TsnSwitch. It should have ExtendedGptp.
module ExtendedSwitch extends TsnSwitch
{
parameters:
  gptp.typename="ExtendedGptp";
  @class(inet::ExtendedSwitch);
gates:
  input In;
  output Out;
submodules:
  ExtendedGptp : <default("Gptp")> like IApp if typename !=""{
  @display("p=461,762");
}
connections allowunconnected:
Out<--ExtendedGptp.socketOut;
ExtendedGptp.socketIn--> In;
}

Here I should say that "socketIn" and "socketOut" are gates of Gptp module.
Due to ihneritance I have these gate too
In result gate "Out" stays unconnected.
I listed all gates name and its EndGates.
Here is the output
INFO: In    (omnetpp::cGate)In <-- <parent>.In
INFO: Out   (omnetpp::cGate)Out not connected


I also tried this way
simple ExtendedGptp extends Gptp
{
  gates:
   input In;
   output Out;
  
}
module ExtendedSwitch extends TsnSwitch
{
parameters:
  gptp.typename="ExtendedGptp";
  @class(inet::ExtendedSwitch);
gates:
  input In;
  output Out;
submodules:
  ngptp : ExtendedGptp 
  {
  @display("p=461,762");
}
connections allowunconnected:
Out<--ngptp .Out;
ngptp.In--> In;
}


But there is no result. Anyway gate "Out" is not connected. Maybe you know what I can try. Please help
